# How to compare __m128 types?

Tags: x86, sse, simd

```
__m128 a;
__m128 b;
```

How to code `a != b` ?

what to use: `_mm_cmpneq_ps` or `_mm_cmpneq_ss` ?

How to process the result ?

Can't find adequate docs.

Comment: I hope you understand why it's not a good idea to compare floating point values for equality/inequality ? (This applies to both scalar code and SIMD code.)

Comment: Docs are available from Intel and AMD.  Look for processor manuals.

Comment: @Paul R: SIMD code is not necessarily floating point.

Comment: @Dietrich: I know, but it is in this particular case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should probably use `_mm_cmpneq_ps`. However the interpretation of comparisons is a little different with SIMD code than with scalar code. Do you want to test for *any* corresponding element not being equal ? Or *all* corresponding elements not being equal ?

To test the results of the 4 comparisons from `_mm_cmpneq_ps` you can use `_mm_movemask_epi8`.

**Note that comparing floating point values for equality or inequality is usually a bad idea, except in very specific cases.**

```
__m128i vcmp = (__m128i)_mm_cmpneq_ps(a, b); // compare a, b for inequality
uint16_t test = _mm_movemask_epi8(vcmp); // extract results of comparison
if (test == 0xffff)
    // *all* elements not equal
else if (test != 0)
    // *some* elements not equal
else
    // no elements not equal, i.e. all elements equal
```

For documentation you want these two volumes from Intel:

[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual
Volume 2A: Instruction Set Reference, A-M](http://www.intel.com/assets/pdf/manual/253666.pdf)
[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual
Volume 2B: Instruction Set Reference, N-Z](http://www.intel.com/assets/pdf/manual/253667.pdf)

Comment: BTW, in Visual Studio the regular C++ casts don't work, but you can still cast to __m128i  using the intrinsic _mm_castps_si128

Comment: @Virgil: yes, this is just one of several problem areas with the Visual Studio C/C++ compilers and SSE code - there are some nasty (and seemingly arbitrary) ABI restrictions too. I recommend using gcc or better still Intel's ICC, and avoid Windows if humanly possible. ;-)

Comment: You'd normally want `_mm_movemask_ps` here, to get a simple 4-bit mask in the low bits of a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question also depends on whether you want actual inequality where you'd use something along the lines of what @PaulR has shown:

```
bool fneq128_a (__m128 const& a, __m128 const& b)
{
    // returns true if at least one element in a is not equal to 
    // the corresponding element in b
    return _mm_movemask_ps(_mm_cmpeq_ps(a, b)) != 0xF;
}
```

or whether you want to use some epsilon to specify that elements are still considered to be "equal" if they do not differ more than the threshold:

```
bool fneq128_b (__m128 const& a, __m128 const& b, float epsilon = 1.e-8f)
{
    // epsilon vector
    auto eps = _mm_set1_ps(epsilon);
    // absolute of difference of a and b
    auto abd = _mm_andnot_ps(_mm_set1_ps(-0.0f), _mm_sub_ps(a, b));
    // compare abd to eps
    // returns true if one of the elements in abd is not less than 
    // epsilon
    return _mm_movemask_ps(_mm_cmplt_ps(abd, eps)) != 0xF;
}
```

Example:

```
auto a = _mm_set_ps(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
auto b = _mm_set_ps(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.e-15);
std::cout << fneq128_a(a, b) << ' ' << fneq128_b(a, b) << "\n";
```

Prints:

```
 1 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Peter is right!!! Tests against values that are 0.0f can fail under the previous approach.

Please consider this MACRO.
#define ISEQUAL(A, B) _mm_testz_si128(_mm_xor_si128(_mm_castps_si128(A), _mm_castps_si128(B)),   
_mm_xor_si128(_mm_castps_si128(A), _mm_castps_si128(B)))

This results in 2 instructions.

Comment: That's not a test for equality, that's testing if `~a & b == all-zero`  (Across all 128 bits).    See also [Can PTEST be used to test if two registers are both zero or some other condition?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43712243)

Comment: Making it a macro is inconvenient; you might as well make it an inline function so you can use a temporary to hold the bitwise XOR result.  But yes, this should work if you want to test for bitwise equality, considering NaN == NaN (with the same payload), and `-0.0 != 0.0`.  Instead of IEEE floating-point equality rules.