# Replacement of "typedef int64_t x_t __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've come across the above typedef in some code I'm trying to compile under VS2013 Community C++.

I've found references to __declspec(align(16)) and allignas(16), but no matter how I try to use these in conjunction with typedef some part of the code complains; with this typedef:

```
typedef __declspec(align(16)) int64_t   x_t;
```

I get the following errors, for the function declaration:

```
bool funcSame(x_t e1, x_t e2)
{
return e1[eStart] == e2[eStart] && e1[eEnd] == e2[eEnd];
}
```

The above errors at all '[' with: no operator "[]" matches these operands

For the variable declaration:

```
x_t a = { 0, 0 }; // at the 2nd '0' error too many initializer values
```

The code relies on x_t being treated as a vector of two 64bit values that take advantage of SSE operations.

Could someone please explain how I can replace this typedef to get the code to compile and use SSE operations?

Thank you,
    Graham....

Comment: What has `eval_t` to do with `x_t`?

Comment: @Kerrek: thanks for spotting that, I have edited. I was trying to remove context to help focus on the problem.

Comment: Since `x_t` is a simple type (like `long`), unless `eEnd` and `eStart` are both pointers, the `e1[eEnd]` (etc) notation is bound to be erroneous.

Comment: @Jonathan: eStart & eEnd are part of an enum with values 0 and 1 respectively. The gcc compiler appears to use the typedef to define a type that is 2 contiguous 64bit values, and then allows indexing (by 0 and 1) within the type.

Comment: Maybe the 'vector size' means that, but `typedef __declspec(align(16)) int64_t   x_t;` doesn't declare an array type and I'm moderately confident that's the cause of your compilation errors.  Only moderately confident; I've not worked with the vector size notation so I've not studied what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read [the documentation for the `vector_size` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) correctly, alignment is only part of the result (although it isn't even mentioned on the linked page, SIMD is mentioned, and SSE needs, well prefers, aligned operands).

Unfortunately, I don't think a direct 1:1 alternative exists. VC++ intrinsics include the type [`__m128`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ayeb3ayc.aspx), which is a 16-byte aligned type that has the same size as your "vector".

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6042399/256138) for how to compare two `__m128` variables.

Comment: @rubenb: Yes from other threads relating to this topic (usually associated with a struct union type) it seems that a 1:1 is not available. For now I've commented out the use of this type throughout the code to gat a clean compilation. And I think the answer may be a re-write of those sections specifically for MSVC using __m128 and relevant intrinsics.